# how to validate textfield that allows only 0,1,..9 and . symbol

Tags: iphone

i place 4 textfields in my application.

I need that 4 textfields allows only numbers 0,1...9 and . symbol.

For that i place keyboard numbers&punctuation. it is ok but In [my keypad](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6f28d228b2.jpg) allows   ABC,-,/,(,that all are  activated.

But in my textfield, that allows only 0,1,...9 and . symbol.

How can i done this.

can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 4.1 and later, you can use UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad. If you need to support older versions, require a decimal point, and don't want anything else, you will have to create a custom keyboard.

If you want to filter out the other keys without removing them, assign some object as the text field's delegate. That object should contain the following code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    static NSCharacterSet *charSet = nil;
    if(!charSet) {
        charSet = [[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet] retain];
    }
    NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
    return (location.location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Comment: is it not possible with the default keypad that allow only o,1,..9 and . for textfield

Comment: The UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad type only shows them, but is only available in 4.1 and later. For older versions, you can filter out the other keys in your view, but the buttons would still be visible to the user.

Comment: No problem if buttons are visible...And i use 4.1 and later versions then how can i filter them.

Comment: ya it works but,ABC And #+- buttons are also in active.But it is Possible inactivate them

Comment: Sorry, but not that I know of.